# Laravel Datatables multiple actions edit / delete, delete displayed as text

Tags: laravel, datatables

I use datatables yajra/laravel-datatables package. I am almost there but the delete button is displays in text.

How can i display it as a button or link?

Data:

```
    return Datatables::eloquent(Product::query())
        ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/prodicts/'. $row->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        })
        ->addColumn('delete', function ($row) {
            return '<a href="/products/show/1">delete</a>';
        })
        ->make(true);
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#users').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        responsive: true,
        columnDefs: [
            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -2 },
            { responsivePriority: 3, targets: -1 }
        ],
        "ajax": "http://admin/products",
        "columns": [

            <?php echo $string;  ?>
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {data: 'delete', name: 'delete', orderable: false, searchable: false}

        ],
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, ->rawColumns:

```
    return Datatables::eloquent(Product::query())
        ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/prodicts/'. $row->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        })
        ->editColumn('delete', function ($row) {
            return '<a href="/products/show/1">delete</a>';
        })
        ->rawColumns(['delete' => 'delete','action' => 'action'])
        ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `class="btn btn-danger"` to your delete anchor. just like your edit link.

```
return Datatables::eloquent(Product::query())
        ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
            return '<a href="/prodicts/'. $row->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        })
        ->addColumn('delete', function ($row) {
            return '<a href="/products/delete/1" class="btn btn-danger">delete</a>';
        })
        ->make(true);
```

Comment: Thnx! But found the solution.